# Reading Validation-Dataset takes indefinitely long

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

I've got a custom TensorFlow Dataset and my problem is , that my Validation Dataset is loading indefinitely, if i try to access the first item.

So `next(iter(train_ds.take(1)))` returns the first Training-Data as expected, but `next(iter(val_ds.take(1)))` loads indefinitely.

My Dataset Contains multiple Image-Path-Triplets (`<ZipDataset shapes: ((), (), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.string, tf.string)>`).

My-Preprocessing looks something like this:

```py
buffer_size = 1024
batch_size = 32

def prep_image(filename, img_shape=(144,144), channels=3, dtype=tf.float32):
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=channels)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, img_shape)
    return image

def preprocess_triplet(a, p, n):
    return prep_image(a), prep_image(p), prep_image(n)

dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)
dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_triplet)

# splitting the ds
split = .8
n_train_items = round(len(dataset) * split) #r(514551 * 0.8) = 411641

train_dataset = dataset.take(n_train_items)
val_dataset = dataset.skip(n_train_items)

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=False)
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE) #.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=False)
val_dataset = val_dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

When i run `next(iter(train_dataset.take(1)))` im getting my Image-Triplets as Tuple of Arrays (as expected). When i try to do the same on the Validation-Dataset it runs forever `type(next(iter(val_dataset.take(1))))`.

##### Verbose Version - Containing `sanity` Checks

`python next(iter(dataset))`

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'F:\\workspace\\datasets\\own_256\\hm\\pics\\bf\\67\\bf67f3922e8245954943f1479961d932d56ef0ad.jpg'>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'F:\\workspace\\datasets\\own_256\\hm\\pics\\4b\\03\\4b03c337d013500930b71f9999766656f5893946.jpg'>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'F:\\workspace\\datasets\\own_256\\asos\\pics\\products\\asos-design-petite-halter-midi-beach-dress-in-double-gauze-in-sage-green\\24233155-2.jpg'>)
```

After Loading the Dataset and Shuffling

```py
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)
dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_triplet)
```

i just tried to "load" each entry, to check if the Images can be read:

```py
for img in dataset:
    a, b, c = img
    assert a.shape == (144, 144, 3) and b.shape == (144, 144, 3) and c.shape == (144, 144, 3)
```

This run without any problems.

Afterwards i tried to Split the Dataset into Validation and Test

```py
split = .8
n_train_items = round(len(dataset) * split) #r(514551 * 0.8) = 411641

train_dataset = dataset.take(n_train_items)
val_dataset = dataset.skip(n_train_items)
```

To test if i can access the Items i just called the first item of the batch per Val/Train DS:

```py
next(iter(train_dataset))
```

```sh
$(<tf.Tensor: shape=(144, 144, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array(..., dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(144, 144, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array(..., dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(144, 144, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array(..., dtype=float32)>)
```

Also tried to iterate over all Train Data and it worked

```py
print("t_items")
test_n_items = sum([sum([1 for item in a])for a, p, n in train_dataset])
print(test_n_items == n_train_items)
$True
```

But i cant even get the first item of Validation Dataset

```py
next(iter(val_dataset))
```

Sadly the Second `next(iter(val_dataset))` runs indefinitely.

Some Info

```py
len(dataset)
$ 514551
len(train_dataset)
$411641
len(val_dataset)
$len(val_dataset)
len(dataset) == len(train_dataset) + len(val_dataset)
$True
```

##### Edit 1:

The Problem is withing`prep_image`, when i just return the Filename without opening the Data everything works as expected:

```py
def prep_image(filename, img_shape=(144,144), channels=3, dtype=tf.float32):
    return filename
#    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
#    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=channels)
#    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype)
#    image = tf.image.resize(image, img_shape)
#    return image
```

Just reading the File:

```py
def prep_image(filename, img_shape=(144,144), channels=3, dtype=tf.float32):
    return tf.io.read_file(filename)
```

already produces the error of waiting for ever on Val-Dataset (Train still works).

##### Edit 2:

Simple Code to Reproduce the Issue:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1w5RQDp6W3Zyu4p1kEBRlHT2Vl9zvxVOk?usp=sharing

##### Edit 3:

Loading the first Item within the Training-Dataset (from the example of ´Edit 2`takes` 0.6 ms`and loading the first item of the Validation Dataset takes`31.09 Minutes`